# Strange padding not happening on layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a registration screen strangely I am facing an issue with padding a layout which has sign up text.

I would like to align it according to text box shown in the screen shot below. I am not sure why this giving me this strange issue?

Below is the code I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/signUp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namefEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/fname"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fnamelinearlayout"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namelEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/lname"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lnamelinearlayout"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/mobilenumber"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mobilelinearlayout"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordlinearlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/signText"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
 </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Move `android:padding="10dp"` from `textEdit` to `linearlayout5`. Although I think you are overthinking the layout. It can be done with less code

Comment: @CarlosJ : I changed it and but difference. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: padding means `inside the component`. The padding is happening. You may want to use a margin instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This layout should do the same:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/signUp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namefEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/fname"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namelEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/lname"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/mobilenumber"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pEDIT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/signText"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```